# Erasing a rectangular area of PIL image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How can I erase and make transparent a rectangular area of a PIL image, without changing dimensions?

I implemented this by cropping the image & pasting on an empty image, but it cannot erase an area inside the image. My implementation is mostly just arithmetic, so I am trying to find a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open it in RGBA mode.

```
from PIL import Image

rect_size = (100, 300)
rect_pos = (200, 400)

im = Image.open("your-image.jpg").convert("RGBA")
rect = Image.new("RGBA", rect_size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
im.paste(rect, rect_pos)
im.show()
```

Comment: iterating through each pixel in python abstraction level is costly :(

Comment: @nipunasudha You could convert them to numpy arrays if you wanted. But for a normal size image (in the ballpark of 1920 x 1080) you probably won't notice the difference.

Comment: here I improved it using `paste()` instead of putpixel. This will definitely be faster. (I figured out how to do it after 1 minute of google searching.)

Comment: wooohhh! now that IS elegant! thank you @helper, answer accepted.